# windows 10 - change default windows browser to a portable app application, Firefox or Chrome

Tags: windows-10, browser, default-settings

Can you change Windows 10 default browser to a portable app, Firefox or Chrome/chromium portable from portableapps.com

In
Start (windows logo) > Settings > System > Default Apps > Web Browser > Click on Microsoft edge > select your favorite browser.

it only offers as options :

Microsoft Edge

Internet Explorer

Search for app in windows store

[image: screen capture]

Comment: The best way is from the application itself at first. Every browser leaves you the option to choose it as default in its own settings/parameters/options. Doing so will create an entry in Registry that Windows Settings will read, and propose your portable browser in the list of candidates. EDIT: that's unless you've got a GPO in place on your PC to prevent you from choosing your own default browser, of course.

Comment: Didier, thank you for your detailed answer.
It worked.
If you want to propose it as a full answer and I will accept it the better answer.
Thanks!

Comment: Done. And glad you solved your issue. It works with other default apps, such as PDF reader or image reader, by the way, provided they offer to be set as default in their preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is from the application itself at first.

Every browser leaves you the option to choose it as default in its own settings/parameters/options.

Doing so will create an entry in Registry that Windows Settings will read, and propose your portable browser in the list of candidates.

That's unless you've got a GPO in place on your PC to prevent you from choosing your own default browser, of course.

Comment: This does not work with a fresh Firefox as of 2020–2021. It just opens the Windows Settings for you to choose the browser manually.

Comment: This works, but my problem is when opening an external link... it opens a new instance of the browser, and not the one that is in use!!! Sucks... Any ideas?